# Shell Script to unzip files and read them sequentially

Tags: linux, shell

I have a list of zipped folders which contains xml files in it.
I want to write a linux shell script which unzips the folder sequentially , read them and print the file name if it contains particular string say "Apple INC."

I have tried following code.

```
for x in *.zip
do unzip $x
if grep -i "Apple INC" $x
then
echo $x
fi
done
```

can anyone help me in getting it right?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `unzip -p` to unzip files to standard output, and pipe the output directly to `grep`. The `-q` options prevents `grep` from outputting the matching lines.

```
for z in *.zip ; do
    if unzip -p "$z" | grep -qi 'apple inc' ; then
        echo "$z"
    fi
done
```

Have you noticed how the code is indented?